# What are some empirical ways to estimate the absolute 0 in temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, low-temperature-physics

Back in the 1600's and 1700's, people could estimate the existence of an absolute 0 in temperature by using the ideal gas law $PV=nRT$. By holding $P$ and $n$ constant and by observing how much gases reduce their volume when cooled down, it is possible to extrapolate to low temperatures until $V=0$. The exact temperature at which this occurs is the absolute 0. This is how they could estimate a roughly $-260°C$ without reaching those low temperatures.

I am wondering whether there are other "experimental ways" to estimate quantitatively the absolute 0 in temperature. Any ideas?

Comment: Before about 1700, people were hardly aware that temperature existed.

Comment: You're right but they could still hypothesize that there could exist an object colder than any other. But scratch 1600s and let 1700s if you prefer.